# Reducing number of groups of overlapping objects

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics, probability

I have a long list of groups of objects. Each object has simple properties like a name and description. They are already are grouped with similar objects but I know many of the groups are redundancies or overlap in some way. The lists do not contain repeated objects and order does not matter.

Any suggestions for how to reduce them down to "n" groups based on similarity? Thank you.

Ie for strings

```
["apple", "orange", "pear"]
["apple", "steak", "orange"]
["steak", "burger"]
```

The first two are the most similar roughly

Comment: And how do you define similar?

Comment: Hi, I define it by having the same set of objects within the list. The object could be seen as a simple string or number if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try setting up a matrix where the number of columns corresponds to the number of distinct words in your dataset. The number of rows are number of your data points. Then the entry (i,j) is how many times the word j appears in your sample i.

Once you have this matrix, then any common clustering algorithms will work, and you can define similarity in whatever means you like.